# What does an empty while loop do in C?

Tags: c, loops, while-loop

In this code, what is the use of the while loop? I don't really understand what the loop iterates over if we have nothing in the body.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char str[666];
    char * p1, *p2;

    strcpy ( str, "Hello world!");

    p2 = (p1 = str) + 6;
    
    while ( *p1++ = *p2++ ) {}
        printf ( "%p %p", p1, p2);
}
```

Comment: Can you see the assignment operator? Can you see the pointers being incremented?

Comment: is this contrived as part of an assignment?

Comment: You should fix your indentation so that final printf doesn't appear at first glance to be part of the while loop. Doesn't make a difference to the compiler, but it's misleading to humans.

Comment: Also, the pointers used as arguments for `%p` specifiers need to be cast to `void *` to be compliant with the standard.

Comment: @Fe2O3 i do, but I'm not sure about the assignment part. Does it evaluate to true if p1 and p2 are non-zero, or is it checking some other condition?

Comment: The value of the expression is the value (of the character) being copied... When the character is the NUL at the end of the string, the expression will evaluate to 0 (or `false`) and the loop will terminate.

Comment: @Fe2O3 so as I understand the loop is simply copying p2 to p1?

Comment: Correct. The contents of `str[]` changes: `"Hello world!\0"` to `"world!\0orld!\0"`

Comment: It's *the* traditional example of an implementation of `strcpy()`.

Comment: I have a habit of writing these 'empty' loops without braces: `while (*p1++ = *p2++);` Just to intimidate unsuspecting readers even more.

Answer (score 3):

The post-increment operations (`++`) in the predicate of the `while` loop have side-effects that change the values of `p1` and `p2` on every evaluation of the predicate. That's being done before every loop iteration, despite there being nothing else in the loop body being done in the actual iteration.

The semantics of this is roughly the same as:

```
*p1 = *p2;
while (*p1) {
    p1++;
    p2++;
    *p1 = *p2;
}
p1++;
p2++;
```

Some points to note:

1. In C, assignments are expressions which evaluate to the left hand side. E.g. `while (a = b)` will evaluate as if you first assigned `b` to `a`, then had `while (a)`
2. The predicate runs before every loop iteration, unlike the loop body, isn't skipped. This is why you see the final 2 increments.

Comment: Subtle difference: `while ( *p1++ = *p2++ ) {}` leaves `p1` and `p2` pointing to the memory locations _following_ the trailing NUL characters.

Comment: @RuudHelderman ah right, so I need one more pair of increments after the loop?

Comment: Correct! BTW, it makes sense to do `while (*p1 != '\0')` as people new to C may not be aware that `0`, `'\0'` and false are the same value.

Comment: The two final increments at the end are very likely useless though, they are just a flaw in the `while ( *p1++ = *p2++ )` method. The original answer was better - simply drop the pointless increments from the code here and then we've written a much better loop than `while ( *p1++ = *p2++ )`.

Comment: @Lundin my goal isn’t to write a better version of this code. If it was, I’d just call `strcopy` and call it a day. Instead, im trying to show a clearer equivalent of what’s going on in the provided code.

Answer (score 0):

```
while ( *p1++ = *p2++ ) {}
```

It assigns the object referenced by the `p2` with the object referenced by the `p1`. If the object referenced by the `p2` is `0` it will exit the loop after increment both pointers, otherwise it will increment both pointers and loop again.

In this case, this loop is copying the C string.

Comment: The term is `increment` rather than `increase`... And, what is the _magical_ "it" that you are referring to...

Answer (score 0):

Here are some explanations:

- the code is not indented properly: the `while` loop and th efollowing statement should read:

  ```
      while ( *p1++ = *p2++ ) {}
      printf("%p %p", p1, p2);
  ```
- `while ( *p1++ = *p2++ ) {}` repeatedly evaluates the condition, which has the value of the character pointed to by `p2`, and has 3 side effects: the said byte is copied to the address pointed by `p1` and both `p1` and `p2` are incremented.  Nothing happens in the body of the loop but the next iteration handles the next character until a null byte is copied and tested. This loop could be written equivalently in other ways:

  ```
      while ( *p1++ = *p2++ );   // even more confusing
  ```

  I personally prefer more a explicit test that prevent compiler warnings and avoid an empty body:

  ```
      while ((*p1++ = *p2++) != '\0')
          continue;
  ```
- the loop copies the string pointed to by `p2`, `"world!"`, over the beginning of the string pointed to by `p1`, `"Hello world!"`.  These strings overlap, but the loop iterates from the first character to and including the null terminator and `p2 > p1` so the net effect is the array `str` contains these bytes after the loop completes:

  ```
  'w'|'o'|'r'|'l'|'d'|'!'|'\0'|'o'|'r'|'l'|'d'|'!'|'\0'|...
  ```
- `p1` points to `str+7` and `p2` points to `str+13` after the loop, past the null terminator of the destination, respectively the source, strings.
- `printf("%p %p", p1, p2)` has undefined behavior because it expects `void *` pointers for `%p`, but `p1` and `p2` have type `char *`.  This is actually debatable as `char *` and `void *` are supposed to have the same representation.

It is worth mentioning that the empty loop copies the overlapping strings correctly in this case whereas `strcpy(p1, p2)` would have undefined behavior in all cases of overlapping strings.